# Ract FontAwesome ES6 usage

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, font-awesome

Good day

I am a novice React developer building a site for a client using ES6 standards. I have found a component for which the usage as description uses an older syntax, and I am having some trouble implementing my code. I am receiving an error message that I am not sue how to resolve.

The component in questions can be seen here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fontawesome

it instructs you to use the component as follows:

```
var React = require('react');
var FontAwesome = require('react-fontawesome');

React.render(<FontAwesome name='rocket' />, document.body);
```

To my understanding, this is an older way of writing React code. I have thus updated my code to for the ES6 standard.
I scratched in my package.json file to find out where to import the component from, so I am not sure if this is perhaps where I have gone wrong.

Below is a copy of my code using what I believe to be the correct implementation:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FontAwesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

export class Footer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render = _ => {
    return (
      <div>
       <FontAwesome name='rocket' />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I import the component and run the code I get the following error:

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named
>   imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Footer`.
>       in Footer (created by App)
>       in div (created by App)

If anyone would be kind enough to let me know where I might be going wring, I would be incredibly grateful.

Comment: What makes you think that's the "correct implementation"? Why are you importing fontawesome-svg-core and try to use it as a React component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple example on their [docs page](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome) that should help out:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const element = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />

ReactDOM.render(element, document.body)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance. As I mentioned, I am very new to the platform. I know know where to look for such solutions in the future